# How can we verify if link is exist using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, assertion

I try to use this code but how can i verify the link if have more than one link ?

Assert.assertNotNull(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Read more")).isDisplayed());
System.out.println("link exists");

[image]

Comment: Can you share the link of this website ? Also, what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Actually, i try to check if the element is clickable or not by check the linktext.